# Get first value after Where-Object condition

Tags: powershell

Give the following command how to get only the first value after the `where` condition?

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname = 'Security';EndTime=$Time; ID = 5379} |
  select id , TimeCreated, @{ n='USER'; E ={ $_.Properties[1].Value}} |
  where USER -notlike 'condition'
```

I tried `-MaxEvents 1` and `-First 1` but that applies only to `Select-Object`, doesn't work with `where`.

Comment: Put `|Select -First 1` _after_ `Where`

Comment: Pipe the output of the `where` into the `| Select-Object -First 1`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pipe your results to `Select-Object -First 1` like so:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname = 'Security';EndTime=$Time; ID = 5379} |
  Select-Object Id , TimeCreated, @{ n='USER'; E ={ $_.Properties[1].Value}} | 
  Where-Object { $_.USER -notlike 'condition' } |
  Select-Object -First 1
```

Comment: FYI In the name of readability i made a couple goofs that I fixed in the block just now

Comment: Thank you ! First time trying PowerShell !! :) Have a nice Day !